# MySQL sum of subquery containing join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum

I have a table containing inventories in the form

```
ID |Product ID | Movement |  Cumulative Quantity | Store ID
=================================================|=========
1  | 1         |  100     |  100                 |  1 
2  | 1         |  -4      |  96                  |  1
3  | 1         |  -1      |  95                  |  1
4  | 2         |  100     |  100                 |  1
5  | 1         |  100     |  100                 |  2
```

Every line basically has a movement of stock and the last line MAX(ID) contains cumulative_quantity which contains the stock available

Another table containing products

```
ID | Product Name
====================
1  | Apple Juice
2  | Orange Juice
```

I'm looking for output in the form

```
Product ID | Product Name | Total Quantity at all stores
========================================================
1          | Apple Juice  | 195
2          | Orange Juice | 100
```

This is a simplified version of the following table

```
Store ID   | Product ID | Product Name | Cumulative Quantity
========================================================
1          | 1          | Apple Juice  | 95
1          | 2          | Orange Juice | 100
2          | 1          | Apple Juice  | 100
2          | 2          | Orange Juice | 0
```

Comment: Did the cumulative quantity are stored in the same row where the movement occurs or in the next column, i.e you said that you are looking for output for the second product = 200 this means that cumulative quantity + movement that inserted in the same row = 200, but for the first Product the cumulative quantity = sum(Movement) which equal 100 for the second product, i mean it will be right if the total quantity for the second product = 100

Comment: @Mga I think its safe to assume that the OP has some mistakes in the Sample data.

Comment: sure @ConradFrix, but i am just trying to understand what the OP looking for.am i doing wrong by this comment?? if you look to the output form the OP looking form the two rows are not computed by the same way

Comment: Im sorry i could have made it simpler to understand each Store and each Product have their own unique quantity, so Store ID 1 has 95 units of Product 1 (Apple Juice), Store ID 1 has 100 units of product id 1, Store ID 2 has 0 units of product ID 2 and Store ID 2 has 100 units of product id 1.

Comment: @MGA sorry, I didn't mean to imply that your comment had any problem. Just that errors in sample data and output are common and that in this case its probably pretty clear what it should have been, and if you want to provide an answer you should probably assume that its 200 and 195 for records 4 and 5.

Comment: I have updated the data to make it clearer

Comment: @Akshat in the output for product ID 2 still doesn't match the sample data.

Comment: My sample data did have errors terribly sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several ways to do this here's one

**Sub-query in From Clause using MAX**

```
SELECT products.id as `Product ID`,  
       products.`Product Name`, 
       SUM(inventory.`Cumulative Quantity`) as Total Quantity at all stores
FROM products
     INNER JOIN inventory
     ON products.`id` = inventory.`id`
     INNER JOIN 
     (
     SELECT ( max(`id`)  as `id`,
              `product id`,
              `store id`
     FROM 
           `inventory`
     GROUP BY
              `product id`,
              `store id`) maxinventory
     ON inventory.`id` = maxinventory.`id`
GROUP BY
      products.`id`,  
       products.`Product Name`
```

Here's another  **using IN**

```
SELECT products.id as `Product ID`,  
       products.`Product Name`, 
       SUM(inventory.`Cumulative Quantity`) as Total Quantity at all stores
FROM products
     INNER JOIN inventory
     ON products.`id` = inventory.`id`
WHERE
      inventory.`id ` IN
     (
     SELECT ( max(`id`)  as `id`,
     FROM 
           `inventory`
     GROUP BY
              `product id`,
              `store id`) 
GROUP BY
      products.`id`,  
       products.`Product Name`
```

Comment: I also need to sum up the inventories from two different stores (store id 1 and 2)

Answer (score 3):

This is a relatively simple `SUM()` aggregate with a `JOIN`. `SUM(Movement)` will result in the total quantity available across all stores.

```
SELECT
  inventories.productId,
  productName,
  SUM(Movement) AS `Total Quantity`
FROM inventories JOIN  products ON inventories.productId = products.productId
GROUP BY inventories.productId, productName
```

Comment: is there a way to use the cumulative version, using the movement simply uses too many resources over millions of records

Comment: @Michael, but this will return 100 for the second Product, i think the result could by first quantity + movement for the second product so that the result = 200 as the OP looking for but for the first product sum(movement)

Comment: @MGA The data sample is assumed to have an error or be incomplete, because there is only a single record for product 2. That data set cannot produce the example output asked for.

Comment: i fixed the error in the sample data, apologies for that, been a long day

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a subquery to find the current inventory records, i.e. those that have the maximum `id` for each `product_id, store_id` pair:

```
SELECT
  product_id, name, SUM( cumulative_qty ) AS total_qty
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM inventories GROUP BY product_id, store_id) AS cur
  NATURAL JOIN inventories
  JOIN products ON products.id = inventories.product_id
GROUP BY product_id
```

(BTW, I suspect that you want an index on `inventories (product_id, store_id, id)` to make this query reasonably efficient.  And of course I assume that the `id` columns are primary keys.)